# Damped Harmonic Oscillation , Damping Ratio Derivation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

In Damped Harmonic Oscillation we have:

$F = m\ddot{x} = -kx - c\dot{x}$

$\ddot{x}+\frac{c}{m}\dot{x}+\frac{k}{m}x = 0$

Where $k = m\omega^{2}$. I often see the whole equation written as:

$\ddot{x}+2\gamma\omega\dot{x}+\omega^{2}x = 0$,

where $\gamma$ is the damping factor. In literature it is often written $\gamma = c/2\sqrt{mk}$

My question is, how can we introduce $\gamma$ mathematically leading from the second equation I have written?

Addition: my question is a little vague for what I am really asking, why do we want the equation in the form of:

$\ddot{x} + 2\gamma \omega \dot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0$

why do we want $c/m=2\gamma\omega$ and how do we introduce the parameter $\gamma$ in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking why if we define $\omega$ and $\gamma$ by the formulas above, we can transform the first equation to the second equation?

Comment: @levap my question is how can we move from the second equation to the third, and how we can introduce $\gamma$ in the first place. Or more simply how can we say $c/m = 2\gamma\omega$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with

$$ \ddot{x} + \frac{c}{m} \dot{x} + \frac{k}{m} x = 0 $$

and define two new constants

$$ \omega := \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}, \,\,\, \gamma := \frac{c}{2\sqrt{mk}}. $$

Calculating, we have

$$ \omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}, \\
2 \gamma \omega = 2 \frac{c}{2\sqrt{mk}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{m}\sqrt{k}} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{m}} = \frac{c}{m}. $$

Substituting it into the original equation, we get the equation

$$ \ddot{x} + 2\gamma \omega \dot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0. $$

The standard approach to solving second order linear ODEs is to look for a solutions of the form $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. By plugging it into the equation, we get

$$ \lambda^2 e^{\lambda t} + 2\gamma \omega \lambda e^{\lambda t} + \omega^2 e^{\lambda t} = (\lambda^2 + 2\gamma \omega \lambda + \omega^2) e^{\lambda t} = 0.$$

The polynomial equation (in $\lambda$)

$$ \lambda^2 + 2\gamma \omega \lambda + \omega^2 = 0 $$

is called the characteristic equation of the ODE and the solutions determined the behaviour of the solutions of the ODE. Now, we can complete the square and get the equivalent equation

$$ (\lambda + \gamma \omega)^2 = (\gamma^2 - 1)\omega^2. $$

We have set up the constants in such a way that the behavior of the solutions depends on the constant $\gamma$. Assuming $\omega > 0$, we see that if $\gamma > 1$, we get exponential solutions (as the quadratic equation has two real roots), if $\gamma < 1$, we get oscillatory solutions (as the quadratic equation has two complex roots).

Comment: I am assuming your answer is more if a critism of my question structure?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: Not at all. What I meant to say is that $\omega$ and $\gamma$ are defined in such a way that $2\gamma \omega = \frac{c}{m}$ and $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$ becomes a consequence of the definitions. You may ask why would we even want to write our equation to this form in the first place but that's a different question.

Comment: That is more my question then. why do we want it in that form? My initial hunch is that we would make some guess at a solution for $x(t)$ that contains a constant $\gamma$ in it. But yes why do we want $\ddot{x} + 2\gamma \omega \dot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0$?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: Beyond the physical meaning of the parameters, it is set up in such a way that the behavior of $\gamma$ will dictate the type of solutions of the equation. I've added some details in my answer.

Comment: while that is a nice answer, it still does not explain how $\gamma$ is introduced in the first instance. That is what I really want to know.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your question. You can introduce any constant you want defined in terms of previously given constants by any formula you want. Some choices give more meaningful parameters and some less.